Calculate CAGR with different time periods



0
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I




1
Product
2023
2024
2025
2026

CAGR

Check


2
Product A
500
300
800
600

6.3% =(E2/B2)^(1/3)-1

600 =B2*(1+G2)^3


3
Product B

150
450
570

94.9% =(E3/C3)^(1/2)-1

570 =C3*(1+G3)^2


4
Product C


850
900

5.9% =(E4/D4)^(1/1)-1

900 =D4*(1+G4)^1


5
Total
500
450
2100
2070






6











7






Overall CAGR

Check Overall CAGR


8






11.3%

2070




In Cell G8 I want to calculate the overall CAGR from 2023 to 2026. 
Therefore, I used the following formula for it:
=(SUM(E2:E4)/SUM(B2,C3,D4))^(1/3)-1

When I check this formula in Cell I8 it seems to give the right result:
=SUM(B2,C3,D4)*(1+G8)^3


It all seems to work correctly. However, when I am thinking about it I am not sure if it is really correct because when I look at the formula in Cell G8 it kind of assumes that also Product B and Product C have been existing for 3 years.
In Range G2:G4 I always put the specific number of years to calculate the CAGR.
Maybe I am overthinking this but is there another way to calculate the overall CAGR or even a specific Excel-Formula for this kind of situation?

You might be overthinking. but it really depends on how you define "Overall CAGR". do you want "Overall CAGR" to be a number x, such that B2*(1+x)^3 + C3 * (1+x)^2 + D4 * (1+x)^1 = 2070?

This is not really a programming question. But I believe that since you have cash flows of different durations, you should probably be calculating the IRR, which is approximately 19.1% computed by the formula =IRR({500,150,850,-2070}).

Using XIRR() function as per MSFT documentations you can calculate the CAGR but the construct of your data don't have dates. And given the formula and output you need should be working for you!

@MayukhBhattacharya That is why IRR is a better fit than XIRR The only requirement is that the cash flows occur at regular intervals.

Even I got 19.1% before posting my answer using IRR() but it wasn't matching with the given output of OP.

@MayukhBhattacharya Yes, but that is because his computation of CAGR for the data shown is incorrect, as he himself wondered in his own question.

Maybe you could try this following formula:


=LET(
     Σ, SUM(BYROW(B2:D4,LAMBDA(α,@TOCOL(α/(α<>""),2,1)))),
     Overall_CAGR, (SUM(E2:E4)/Σ)^(1/3)-1,
     Check, Σ*(1+Overall_CAGR)^3,
     IF({1,0},Overall_CAGR, Check))


Or, just to achieve the Overall CAGR
=(SUM(E2:E4)/SUM(BYROW(B2:D4,LAMBDA(α,@TOCOL(α/(α<>""),2,1)))))^(1/3)-1


